# How can I use NTFS partitions in OS X?

Tags: macos, partition

My coworkers use NTFS partitions, and I can't share my data with them, as NTFS on Mac OS X is read-only.

How can I read and write onto NTFS partitions?

Comment: I suggest you use @LessPop_MoreFizz solution because if you use NTFS-3G you may encounter some bugs such as: all NTFS drives will disappear from the "Startup Disk" preference pane

Comment: I'd rather use a solid MacFuse-based solution like NTFS-3G which runs in userspace (it means that if it crashes it won't crash your mac) than an untested, undocumented, not recommended solution in kernelspace (it will crash your mac). See the comments on MacOSX Hints for more evidence. Also, NTFS-3G now is behind a company that makes money off of this.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all for the answers, I will try the NTFS-3G, I will write the feedback

Comment: I used NTFS-3G and works very well, thanks to all :-D

Comment: possible duplicate of [External drive format to be writeable on both Mac and Windows](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9329/external-drive-format-to-be-writeable-on-both-mac-and-windows)

Comment: Any news about *paid* Turexa vs *paid* Paragon behavior on Lion?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/338607/how-to-copy-mac-files-to-external-ntfs-hard-drive

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For free, you can use the [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/2010/06/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010522.html) driver. In order to use it, you have to install [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) first.

In the end, you'll have a prefpane to mount and manage your NTFS drives

[image: ntfs-3g prefpane]

Comment: +1 for NTFS-3G. Used this for a long time and it works well.

Comment: The latest free version is from Oct 2010 http://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/files/NTFS-3G%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X/2010.10.2/ Does it work fine for Lion? The latest paid is 2011.4.1 and they seem to fix some things in it...

Comment: I migrated to Lion last week but i didnt try it, I hope today I can try it and i will give you the feedback

Comment: Apparently OSX Lion or newer is not supported in MacFUSE as it is no longer maintained. Work is though continued in [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.com/).

Comment: Since MacFuse is not longer maintained, I downloaded OSXFuse and then NTFS-3G. Trying to open the hard disk, it gives this error -- `NTFS-3G could not mount /dev/disk2s1
at /Volumes/My Passport because the following problem occurred:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfuse.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g
  Reason: image not found`. Mac OSX version 10.9.5

Answer (score 6):

I payed(34$) for the full NTFS driver from [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/), the free version was not able to safely eject NTFS disks.

Update: starting with Lion, you'll not be able to share the NTFS drives even if you use NTFS-3G or Tuxera NTFS for Mac.

It may be a good idea to reformat your drive to EXFAT in order to overcome these issues. I know it's a real pain and time killer.

Answer (score 5):

You have 3 main choices :

- [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/) (free one)
- [Paragon NTFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) (paid one)

and even [a built-in solution inside Mac OS X](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=785376).

Comment: The latest free NTFS-3G is from Oct 2010 http://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/files/NTFS-3G%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X/2010.10.2/

Answer (score 4):

If you're running Snow Leopard, don't bother with various MacFUSE based solutions - NTFS support is built in, but disabled by default. To enable it, [read this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090913140023382).

> Snow Leopard has the ability to mount NTFS volumes as read/write, but it's not enabled by default -- just read only is supported, as in 10.5. Here's how to get full read/write support for NTFS drives in Snow Leopard. First, uninstall NTFS-3G or Paragon if you're using either one.
>
> Here's how to get read/write support for NTFS drives in Snow Leopard:
>
> 1. In Terminal, type diskutil info /Volumes/volume_name, where volume_name is the name of the NTFS volume. From the output, copy the Volume UUID value to the clipboard.
> 2. Back up /etc/fstab if you have it; it shouldn't be there in a default install.
> 3. Type sudo nano /etc/fstab.
> 4. In the editor, type UUID=, then paste the UUID number you copied from the clipboard. Type a Space, then type none ntfs rw. The final line should look like this: UUID=123-456-789 none ntfs rw, where 123-456-789 is the UUID you copied in the first step.
> 5. Repeat the above steps for any other NTFS drives/partitions you have.
> 6. Save the file and quit nano (Control-X, Y, Enter), then restart your system.
>
> After rebooting, NTFS partitions should natively have read and write support. This works with both 32- and 64-bit kernels. Support is quite good and fast, and it even recognizes file attributes such as hidden files. My thanks go to Chrysaor, a MacRumors user who brought this to our attention.

Alternately, you could use [NTFSMounter](http://ntfsmounter.com/), for a GUI utility to do the same thing.

Comment: The built-in write support is disabled because it is __unstable__. I've corrupted a drive using it.

Answer (score 0):

I use NTFS-3G with really good success, never lost a bit also sharing the same disk with windows machines and a WD media player connected to my TV.

Only very minor issue I've found was that to proper reclaim space from the disk when I delete file I need to run a Maintenance utility or the Disk Utiity to recover space.

See also http://www.phillo.it/?p=9

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good description how to access NTFS partitions. Basically - install NTFS-3G via macports http://fernandoff.posterous.com/ntfs-write-support-on-osx-lion-with-ntfs-3g-f