# Can't Delete/Move folder/files on external HDD

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-disk, disk-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use NTFS partitions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/447/how-can-i-use-ntfs-partitions)

Hi, I just bought a new external HDD, It went well on my PC but I can't delete/move files on it from my macbook.

PS. Im running OS X 10.5.8 on my macbook

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/447/how-can-i-use-ntfs-partitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install 3rd-party software for this, by default OS X just support reading NTFS not writing.

download and install [NTFS-3G](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/ntfs3g.html) and [MacFUSES](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fmacfuse%2F&rct=j&q=macfuse&ei=WOxpTbOKAcSt8APMuejxBw&usg=AFQjCNG0w1SznA8G_znFOE3OVGpk0uszyQ&sig2=ngDD6mbsQFMQ0AczIxYpNg&cad=rja).