# Pasting folder onto a disk on a USB key

Tags: mac

I have Mac and a disk on a USB key, I'm trying to copy a folder and to paste it in the disk on the USB key, but its not pasting.

How can I paste files & folders onto my USB disk?

Comment: I edited the question for clarity, but please do reject my edit or revert the edit if I've missed what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By "disk on key", I assume you mean USB key?

Is your Disk on Key visible on the desktop? If so, can you right click on it, click **Get Info**, make a screenshot of it and paste it here?

If you don't know how to make a screenshot, [click here](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/screencapturemac/ht/macscreenshot.htm)

Then, [**edit**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/13800/edit) your post and add the screenshot.

---

OK, from your screenshot, it appears your USB Key is formated in NTFS. Mac OS X can read it, but cannot write to it natively.

You have two options

- installing **MacFUSE** and **NTFS-3G**.
  Look [**here**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/447/how-can-i-use-ntfs-partitions-on-os-x/448#448) to find out how.
- Backup all your data on your USB key and format it to a format that Mac OS X can read and write natively.
  I advise you to use ExFAT, since both Windows and Mac (since 10.6.5) can write to it.
  For that, use **Disk Utility**, chose your USB Key, select ExFAT, and format.

**Don't forget to backup all your data before formatting!**

Comment: here: http://imageshack.us/f/191/unled2u.png/

Comment: @Daniel I updated y answer.