# My external harddisk is readonly on mac

Tags: macbook-pro, external-disk

I am having a 1Tb external harddisk. Its working perfectly fine on ubuntu and windows. But On mac its read-only. How can I change this.

Comment: With what filesystem is the HD formatted? NTFS?

Comment: If the exHDD is NTFS formatted, you can use either [ntfs-3g(free)][1] or NTFS for Mac([http://www.paragon-software.com/de/home/ntfs-mac/]). [http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your external drive is most probably formatted on Windows and is then in NTFS format.
Check [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/447/how-can-i-use-ntfs-partitions-on-os-x) which will give you the different possibilities you have.